# Get ROWCOUNT of SYSTEM PROCEDURE IN SYBASE ASE 12.5

Tags: database, t-sql, sap-ase, system-procedures

I need to check for a named transaction in another procedure to ensure it has not been executed by anyone else.

But for this question I am trying to leverage a system procedure

```
EXEC sp_transactions 'xid','MyTran1'  -- This will return a result if it finds a named transaction called MyTran1
```

I would like know if it returned a row... RowsReturned > 1

So I did the following

```
BEGIN TRAN MyTran1  -- named transaction
BEGIN TRAN MyTran2  -- named transaction
```

If I run `EXEC sp_transactions` 2 rows are returned

If I run `EXEC sp_transactions  'xid','MyTran1'` - one row is returned

Now I need to do something like

```
DECLARE @nameTranFound int
SET @nameTranFound = EXEC sp_transactions  'xid','MyTran1'
```

I tried using @@RowCount, but it always returns 1

```
EXEC sp_transactions 'xid','Warren1'
SELECT @@RowCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could create a proxy table wrapper for calling `sp_transactions`, then run `select * from <proxy> / select @@rowcount` ... that's likely a bit drastic/overkill for what you want.

Instead, I suggest you take a look at the source code for `sp_transactions` (HINT: it pulls transaction data from `master..systransactions`) and roll your own code that provides exactly what you want to know.

Comment: Yeah, I was leaning towards rolling my own - just wanted to try and avoid that...  :(   

This gives me the text of the sp:     sp_helptext sp_transactions   
So it is doable.   If nothing else lands I will mark this as an answer